# React axios file upload failing - error "Multipart: Boundary not found"

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios

My code isn't working as it should, it keeps receiving a 400 from the server and failing to upload. I must be making mistakes in the react component so please can you take a look for me? All's working in Postman, so the backend code seems fine.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const UploadAvatar = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    };
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("avatar", image);
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/users/me/avatar",
        { formData },
        config
      );
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleUpload}>
        Select image to upload:
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
          name="fileToUpload"
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UploadAvatar;
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? And also check the curl if it's matching with that of postman.

Comment: 400 bad request, yes it's matching :)

Comment: if curl is matching, i dont think there is any issue in the code. you are posting file, try changing `onChange` function to  `onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}`.

Comment: Thanks Nitesh, but I still get a 400 :/

Comment: Did you set base URL properly?

Comment: yes, if I hadn't I'd be getting a 404

Comment: The error sent back is "Multipart: Boundary not found"

Comment: @harryyoung I think the issue is with the headers. try removing `Content-Type`. Browser can generate itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some things you need to do.

This is not related to the problem, but I think it is worth checking:

```js
const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    }
```

1. What scheme is your Authorization (Basic, Bearer, OAuth)?

   . If its a Bearer schema (e.g.), is your `localStorage.getItem("token")` returning only the `token` or is returning `"Bearer {token}"`? For bearer token, you need to include the word `'Bearer'` before the token.
2. The content-type it's not really necessary here, but you can let it there if you prefer.

In your code, you need to do some changes:

In your handleUpload you need to do this:

```js
try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("avatar", image);
      // I just removed the curly brackets from formData
      const response = await api.post("/users/me/avatar", formData, config);
      console.log(response);
} catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
}
```

And in your input file type:

```js
<input
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
          name="fileToUpload"
/>
```

For input file types, the target should be `e.target.files`, wich returns a list of files and each file is a FileList object. As you sending only one image you can set it as `e.target.files[0]` to get the first image.

And that´s all. It should work now! :)
I did a poc here and everything goes ok.

Answer (score 1):

***for bad request***

it happens because  of axios ,
your not sending json data

in your code

```
const response = await axios.post(
        "/users/me/avatar",
        { formData },<---------here is the problem object
         formData  ,<-------try without curly brazes or use below detailed axios 
        config
      );
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
```

change axios

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'myurl',
    data: formData ,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });
```

**another problem**

YOUR SENDING FILES

```
 <input
          type="file"
          onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}<-------wrong e.target.files[0]
          name="fileToUpload"
        />
```

**change**
if u sending mutliple files

```
e.target.files
```

or if you sending single file use

```
e.target.files[0]
```

change code

```
 <input  type="file"
          onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])}
          name="fileToUpload"
        />
```